# Can't transfer files between servers

Tags: sockets, server, port, web-application-firewall

I am trying to connect two servers and transfer some data files from one to to other server using bsp.

But I'm getting an issue as below:

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout: socket is not established

Is it related to firewall? Is a port not open on of of the servers?

Comment: Try running both processes on your local machine, see if you can get it to work without intermediaries such as fire walls. As for your question, it's way too broad and unclear. It could be anything... maybe one of the servers in unplugged. Maybe the code in the servers is buggy... we really don't have enough information to help you.